# Ошибка при установке virtualenv на сервере Ubuntu

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, администрирование

При вводе команды $ pip install virtualenv
на сервере Operating System: Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS возникает ошибка установки микроокружения.

```
Collecting virtualenv
  Using cached virtualenv-20.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (4.9 MB)
Collecting six<2,>=1.9.0
  Using cached six-1.15.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
Collecting importlib-resources>=1.0; python_version < "3.7"
  Using cached importlib_resources-3.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (26 kB)
Collecting filelock<4,>=3.0.0
  Using cached filelock-3.0.12.tar.gz (8.5 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-C0vJNU/filelock/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-C0vJNU/filelock/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-vEf58R
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-C0vJNU/filelock/
    Complete output (3 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    ImportError: No module named setuptools
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

При выводе версии python выходит следующая информация

$ python -V
 `Python 2.7.12`

$ python3 -V
 `Python 3.5.2`

Подскажите что сделать для того чтобы убрать эту ошибку

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sudo apt-get install -y python-setuptools

Comment: Дайте, пожалуйста, чуть более развернутый ответ.